# WildFly deployment fails - "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, dependencies, web-deployment, wildfly

I am new to Web services. I took over some development project from another developer.
Everything was working fine, until I created my own testing project to see how everything fits together. When I reverted back from my testing project to my previous working project, the project compiles but would not start up during deployment. I do not even know where to start looking.

I am using Eclipse Kepler and I deploy to a WildFly server.

The logs show the following error message:

```
10:39:06,146 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "JEM-eap.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ui.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ui.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".beanmanager]"
    ],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ui.war\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.persistenceunit.\"JEM-eap.ear/JEM-ejb.jar#JPA-ejb\".__FIRST_PHASE__"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ui.war\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar"
        ]
    }
}

10:39:06,146 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "JascoEnergy")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/JascoEnergy is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/JascoEnergy is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]"
]}
10:39:06,146 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "JascoEnergy")
]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/JascoEnergy is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]",
        "jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/JascoEnergy is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar]"
    ],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.JascoEnergy",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.JascoEnergy"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".\"JEM-ui.war\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"JEM-eap.ear\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.jdbc-driver.sqljdbc4_jar"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having a similar issue on my project, did you by any chance find a solution to your problem?

Comment: In case you did not find a solution yet, [James Perkins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) [suggested, to a similar issue, to add a beans.xml file](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237035). The OP of that issue made his problem go away by [adding beans.xml to WEB-INF](https://developer.jboss.org/message/858210#858210). I have tried this to my project, but sadly, this did not solve my problem. Anyway, maybe it solves your problem...?

Comment: @Harriet this error can also occur in case if one has misconfigured attributes in the standalone.xml elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem which is very similar to your problem.

The error log actually does tell you where to look, it actually says that your *jdbc-driver* is missing. The file *sqljdbc4.jar* is missing from your WildFly server *deployments* folder. You need to add the jar-file to `<your_wildfly_server_folder> --> standalone --> deployments`. After adding the missing jar-file, deployment works okay for me.

I have come to realize that (at least in my case) something went wrong with a garbage collector on the WildFly server on one of my deploy attempts. This will result in the required jar file (in your case *sqljdbc4.jar*) to be undeployed on the server. As this is a dependency for your own application, deploying your application will not work.

If you see the jar-file present in the *deployments* folder and you still fail to deploy your application, then you need to redeploy the jar-file first. You can probably do this from the WildFly Admin Console, but I have not found out how exactly. You can also do this by going to the *deployments* folder, locate a file named exactly as your missing jar-file but with a .undeployed extension (in your case *sqljdbc4.jar.undeployed*), and just delete it. If all goes well, then WildFly will automatically re-deploy your jar-file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Host name(IP Address) that you have provided in JBoss overview(Eclipse)
I faced the same issue, after correcting IP Address it started working fine